# Rounded rectangle shape with a triangle tail

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to create a xml shape in Android Studio with rounded edges and a triangular tail, I can't seem to get it to work..

what I want is something like this:
 [image]

please help :)

Comment: why don't you just use an image or SVG

Comment: I am not sure but you can use a nine-path image for this purpose.

Comment: Because I need its color to change dynamically during run.

Answer (score 1):

Find an *SVG* file for your shape online and import it as a **Vector drawable**, which will automatically save it as an *XML* file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a xml shape, you can use this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:width="50dp" android:height="10dp" android:left="6dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/primary_background_color"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="7dp" android:height="7dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="40%"
                android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/primary_background_color"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

It will display this [image]

You can play with the values to adjust your liking.